# Heroku : Cannot start meteor.js project

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor, gitlab

Hello there Stack Overflow community,

I'm actually facing an issue for hwich i found some topics, but none of them helped me out, so i ask here in hope of a better luck !

I'm actually usiong Gitlab CI to deploy a meteorJS app to heroku, in case of testing needs of course. Everything works perfectly on gitlab, perhaps, i'm getting this error on heroku :

**/bin/sh: 1: meteor: not found**

Here is the complete log :

`` bash
2018-12-09T19:38:14.656328+00:00 app[api]: Set METEOR_SETTINGS config vars by user xxxxx.xxxxxxx@gmail.com
2018-12-09T19:38:15.953765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-12-09T19:38:30.743460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c meteor\ npm\ install\ \&\&\ meteor\ -s\ settings.json`
2018-12-09T19:38:33.590796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-12-09T19:38:33.570393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-12-09T19:38:33.497325+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: 1: meteor: not found
2018-12-09T19:38:34.200973+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=twiice-production.herokuapp.com request_id=8bb6dd7e-a7a8-4d91-8333-fcebc61fa41e fwd="90.29.71.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-12-09T19:38:34.729142+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=twiice-production.herokuapp.com request_id=f7a0a7b0-6928-461a-a245-733dff3ff7e6 fwd="90.29.71.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-12-09T19:38:42.656886+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-12-09T19:38:57.524320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c meteor\ npm\ install\ \&\&\ meteor\ -s\ settings.json`
2018-12-09T19:39:00.040931+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-12-09T19:39:00.021846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-12-09T19:38:59.954125+00:00 app[web.1]: /bin/sh: 1: meteor: not found ``

I've this **heroku.yml** file at root of my project :

`setup:
  addons:
    - plan: 'mongolab:sandbox'
      as: MONGODB
  config: {}
build:
  languages:
    - nodejs
  pre:
    - curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
run:
  web: meteor npm install && meteor -s settings.json`

I've tried many things, but actually dont know what to do more. Does anyone see any problems ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `bin/sh: 1: meteor: not found` indicates that there is no meteor environment installed. Can you confirm that you have installed meteor on the heroku instance?

Comment: Hi, i've not installed it apparently, i'm trying in the Heroku file to do it. Perhaps, it seems that Heroku do not install it :/

Comment: I am not familiar with heroku but is this the way heroku runs Meteor apps? Usually a Meteor app is built and then it runs on an environment as native nodejs application.

Comment: Okay i see what you mean. I'll try to see what it need then ... I guess i have to find the meteor build process for heroku